# Prestashop BO Module / css and js files not loaded

Tags: javascript, css, module, prestashop-1.5

I am developing a BO module for Prestashop.

For the view I need to add CSS and JS file. I add files in setMedia() function but it is not loaded.

Files are in /views/css and /views/js folders.

The module implementation extended from ModuleAdminController.

Does someone has an idea ?

```
public function setMedia()
{
    $sepa = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    $css_directory = $sepa.'modules'.$sepa.MyModuleCommon::getModuleName().$sepa.'views'.$sepa.'css'.$sepa.'mymoduledashboard.css';
    $this->addCSS($css_directory, 'all');

    $js_directory = $sepa.'modules'.$sepa.MyModuleCommon::getModuleName().$sepa.'views'.$sepa.'js'.$sepa.'mymoduledashboard.js';
    $this->addJS($js_directory, 'all');

    $this->addJqueryUI('ui.datepicker');        

    return parent::setMedia();              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace:
`$sepa.'modules'.$sepa.MyModuleCommon::getModuleName().$sepa.'views'.$sepa.'css'.$sepa.'mymoduledashboard.css'`

with

```
$this->_path.'views/css/mymoduledashboard.css'
```

and replace:
    `$sepa.'modules'.$sepa.MyModuleCommon::getModuleName().$sepa.'views'.$sepa.'js'.$sepa.'mymoduledashboard.js'`

with:

```
$this->_path.'views/js/mymoduledashboard.js'
```